# Как правильно вычислять позицию элемента при drag and drop (перетаскивании)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такая функция перетаскивания:

```js
    const dragAndDrop = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let startCoords = {
            x: e.clientX,
            y: e.clientY
        };

        
        const onMouseMove = moveEvt => {
            moveEvt.preventDefault();
            

            let shift = {
                x: startCoords.x - moveEvt.clientX,
                y: startCoords.y - moveEvt.clientY
            };

            startCoords = {
                x: moveEvt.clientX,
                y: moveEvt.clientY
            };


            e.target.style.position = 'absolute';
            e.target.style.left = (e.target.offsetLeft - shift.x) + 'px';
            e.target.style.top = (e.target.offsetTop - shift.y) + 'px';
            e.target.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            e.target.style.zIndex = 10000;


        };

        const onMouseUp = upEvt => {
            upEvt.preventDefault();
            e.target.style.position = 'static';
            e.target.style.top = 0;
            e.target.style.left = 0;
            e.target.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
            e.target.style.zIndex = 1000;

            const clonedTask = e.target.cloneNode(true);
            const thisTask = e.target;
            const onElem = document.elementFromPoint(upEvt.clientX, upEvt.clientY);
            if (!onElem.classList.contains('deskWrapper') && onElem.closest('.taskDesk_add_box')) {
                onElem.closest('.taskDesk').querySelector('.task_list').appendChild(clonedTask);
                thisTask.remove();
            }



            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
        };

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
    };
```

И есть карточки которые я могу перетаскивать. При перетаскивании первой карточки = все отлично. При перетаскивании второй - она появляется как бы над мышью а не под ней. То есть логично что при присваивании ей `position: absolute` и позиционирования `top` `left` её кидает вверх. Я исследовал эту проблему и нашел похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111492/implementing-drag-and-drop-on-relatively-positioned-elements-in-javascript). 
Пишут что эта ошибка - результат использования `e.target.offsetTop`.

И предлагают такую функцию:

```js
function findPos(obj) {
  var curleft = curtop = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return {
      x: curleft,
      y: curtop
    };
  }
}
```

Подскажите, как правильно ее внедрить, у меня не получилось после многих попыток. Я что-то упускаю. Благодарю за внимание

**p.s. сами карточки выглядят так** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте полностью воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko постараюсь в ближайшие несколько дней!